# Transpose or Convert column data set to multiple columns (variable)!

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, offset, calculated-columns, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a single column data set to multiple columns.

There are no spaces or delimiters. As you can see from data set below, fields are starting from First Name and until the next First Name there's sometimes 3 columns, 4 or even 5.

I have tried to use OFFSET function but it only make sense if you have fixed number of columns between 2 sets that you are comparing.

This is the column data set example:

```
First Name 1
1 Street
Town1 State1 1000
(01) 1234 1234
First Name 2
Town2 State2 2000
(02) 1342 1324
First Name 3
Unit3
3 Street
Town3 State3 3000
(03) 1231 1313
```

This is how it should look with proper coding:

```
First Name 1         1 Street  Town1 State1 1000  (01) 1234 123
First Name 2                   Town2 State2 2000  (02) 1342 1324
First Name 3  Unit3  3 Street  Town3 State3 3000  (03) 1231 1313
```

Or if not possible, perhaps like this:

```
First Name 1  1 Street  Town1 State1 1000  (01) 1234 123
First Name 2  Town2 State2 2000  (02) 1342 1324
First Name 3  Unit3  3 Street  Town3 State3 3000  (03) 1231 1313
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your basic problem is one of  recognising the `First Name` rows of your input column. If each block of data always contains a phone number in a standard format such as `(nn) nnnn nnnn` and it is always the last item of the block then you should be able to exploit this.

Comment: Thank you for your input. There is a way with Offset function but you have to choose fixed number of rows, which then breaks the pattern of sorting with multiple columns if the number shows as 3rd, 4th or 5th.
The problem with number is that not every number is shown with (nn) nnnn nnnn.

But there is a way, if someone knows how to create visual basic code...The number is always with 9 digits after you strip brackets and spaces in between.